# Given Lagrange Optimization

Tags: convex-optimization

I would like to maximize $P = 2pr + 3pq + 2rq$ given that $p+q+3r=1 \wedge p,q,r \geq 0 \wedge p,q,r \leq 1.$ I was considering to develop $P$ as a function of three variables and using standard Lagrange Optimization, but I was wondering if it would be better to reduce $P$ to a function of two variables and then solve for these said variables. I sometimes find working in convex optimization to be slightly tedious.

Comment: It's tedious no matter which way you go. When I substitute for $p$, I get the only critical point is outside the region, so your maximum is on the boundardy. And testing the $p$ boundaries in particular are significant work. I haven't tried both ways, but I suspect Lagrange would actually be less tedious.

Comment: This isn't convex, actually.